# How to get direction between current location to another location on OSM in android studio

Tags: android-studio, osmdroid

*I want to get direction between two location using OSM in android studio. one location is  user current location and other one is  provide my data base . also  assume that there  is two variable called latitude and longitude .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if osmdroid has anything built into the library to calculate distance. But the LocationManager has something you can use. This would be the same myLocationManager you use to initializing your MapView.

[Location.distanceBetween()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D))

Or you can calculate it yourself https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html (It's written in javascript but it's still really worth the read)